# Json file is save like a folder rather than a file

Tags: python, json, operating-system, save

I'm using pixellib package to run machine learning, and when I run my program there is a proccess to create coco dataset with name: `train.json`. But a folder with `train.json` is created wrongly and inside this folder there is a file `dataset.json`, this the file that I need. There is something wrong with the proccess, I found the command that made the coco dataset inside pixellib:

```
def load_dataset(self, dataset):
        labelme_folder1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dataset, "train"))

        #dir where the converted json files will be saved
        save_json_path1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dataset,"train.json"))
        
        #conversion of individual labelme json files into a single json file        
        labelme2coco.convert(labelme_folder1, save_json_path1)
        
        # Training dataset.
        self.dataset_train = Data()
        self.dataset_train.load_data(save_json_path1, labelme_folder1)
        self.dataset_train.prepare()
```

Is there something wrong with the code above?
I've used this program in the past and it worked normally. I tried to contact the developer of the program but to no avail.

Comment: Can you share us your code instead of what's inside pixellib?

Comment: I shared my colab code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version didn't work. I used an old version and now is working.

```
!pip3 uninstall tensorflow
!pip3 install tensorflow==2.4.1
!pip3 install tensorflow--gpu
!pip3 install imgaug
!pip install pixellib==0.5.2
!pip install labelme2coco==0.1.2
```